# mysql GROUP BY and SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

I'm writing a query to give me a salesperson's daily, monthly and total details.
The two tables are:[image][image]

When I write it for daily sales only:

```
SELECT salesperson.user_id AS SalespersonID, CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName) AS Name, COALESCE(SUM(temp1.token_amount),0) AS DailySales
FROM salesperson
LEFT JOIN e4_tokens temp1 ON salesperson.user_id = temp1.createdby_id AND DATE(temp1.created_at) = '2016-05-10' AND temp1.used_flag = 1 
GROUP BY salesperson.user_id
```

I get the correct answer. i.e. Daily Sales = 4000.

But when I add the monthly sales to this query:

```
SELECT salesperson.user_id AS SalespersonID, CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName) AS Name, COALESCE(SUM(temp1.token_amount),0) AS DailySales, COALESCE(SUM(temp2.token_amount),0) AS MonthlySales
FROM salesperson
LEFT JOIN e4_tokens temp1 ON salesperson.user_id = temp1.createdby_id AND DATE(temp1.created_at) = '2016-05-10' AND temp1.used_flag = 1 
LEFT JOIN e4_tokens temp2 ON salesperson.user_id = temp2.createdby_id AND MONTH(temp2.created_at) = 5 AND temp2.used_flag = 1 
GROUP BY salesperson.user_id
```

I get the wrong answer. Both become 8000. I'm missing a very tiny detail here but I have no clue what that is. Help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:

So I worked on it and apparently this query works:

```
SELECT salesperson.user_id AS ID, CONCAT(salesperson.FirstName,' ',salesperson.LastName) AS Name, COALESCE(SUM(temp1.token_amount),0) AS DailySales, COALESCE(SUM(temp2.token_amount),0) AS MonthlySales, COALESCE(SUM(temp3.token_amount),0) AS TotalSales, salesperson.DailyTokenLimit AS DailyLimit, COALESCE(SUM(temp4.token_amount),0) AS NotRedeemed
FROM e4_tokens 
LEFT JOIN e4_tokens temp1 ON e4_tokens.token_id = temp1.token_id AND DATE(temp1.created_at) = '2016-05-10' AND temp1.used_flag = 1 
LEFT JOIN e4_tokens temp2 ON e4_tokens.token_id = temp2.token_id AND MONTH(temp2.created_at) = 5 AND temp2.used_flag = 1 
LEFT JOIN e4_tokens temp3 ON e4_tokens.token_id = temp3.token_id AND temp3.used_flag = 1 
LEFT JOIN e4_tokens temp4 ON e4_tokens.token_id = temp4.token_id AND DATE(temp4.created_at) = '2016-05-10' AND temp4.used_flag = 0 
RIGHT JOIN salesperson ON salesperson.user_id = e4_tokens.createdby_id
GROUP BY e4_tokens.createdby_id
```

Still no idea why the initial query works. Although I'd have preferred if that one had worked!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data as well as the results.  What is the `e4_tokens` table?

Comment: Have you tried `Distinct salesperson.user_id` in SELECT as well as in Group by clause.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: @Gordon, just did!

Comment: can u make fiddle . ? @AzfarKashif